# Getting both values from 2 arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, parallel-processing

How am I able to output the corresponding value from the parallel array. (i.e if I was to search for "John" on the c# console, the corresponding number should appear "34". However, only the name john does. I need to be able to get the corresponding number. Any ideas?

```
        string[] sName = new string [] { "John", "Mary", "Keith", "Graham", "Susan" };
        int[] iMarks = new int [] { 34, 62, 71, 29, 50 };
        int iNumber = 0;
        string sSearch;

        for (iNumber = 0; iNumber < iMarks.Length; iNumber++)
        {
   Console.WriteLine("Number." + (iNumber + 1) + sName[iNumber] + " = " + iMarks[iNumber]);

        }

        Console.WriteLine(" Now can you enter a name to get the marks of the student");
        sSearch = Console.ReadLine();

        while (iNumber < iMarks.Length && sSearch != sName[iNumber])
        {
            iNumber++;              
        }

        if (sName.Contains(sSearch))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sSearch + " Has been found " + iNumber );

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sSearch + " not found, please try again");
        }
```

Comment: Please change the title. This has nothing to do with "parallel" arrays nor "parallel" processing.

Comment: A dictionary would work nicely here

Comment: I copied your code and Ran it in a Console App.... It worked just fine...
No problem found.... @User565656

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat(v=vs.110).aspx) method will help you:

```
string[] sName = new string [] { "John", "Mary", "Keith", "Graham", "Susan" };
int[] iMarks = new int [] { 34, 62, 71, 29, 50 };
string sSearch;

//...
int iNumber = Array.IndexOf(sName, sSearch);

if (iNumber >=0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sSearch + " Has been found " + iMarks[iNumber]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would use a dictionary instead of two arrays, as it already does the "pairing up" of the values.

```
Dictionary<string, int> marksDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

// Just initialize the dictionary instead of the arrays
marksDictionary.Add("John", 34);
marksDictionary.Add("Mary", 62);
marksDictionary.Add("Keith", 71);

// To get the value, simply read off the dictionary passing in the lookup key
Console.WriteLine("Marks for John is " + marksDictionary["John"]);
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would give an example segment of code to demonstrate what you're suggesting with your answer.